# JSON Syntax: Transmitting an array

Tags: json, serialization, data-transfer

A **valid** JSON Syntax is something of the kind:

```
{
  "username": "admin",
  "password": "123"
}
```

But what if I want to transmit an array of 'users' (*given the example*), instead of a single 'user' ?

Is the code below Valid JSON, according to the specifications?

```
[{
  "username": "admin",
  "password": "123"
}, {
  "username": "bbvb",
  "password": "sdfsdf"
}, {
  "username": "asd",
  "password": "222"
}]
```

And if not, what is the best way to transmit an array of values across with JSON? (*And with 'best way', I mean syntactically)*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, your example is valid JSON - that is exactly how you want to use an array.

**Edit** : [Here is a good link on JSON and its usage.](http://www.json.org/fatfree.html)

Answer (score 5):

The not-very-well-known page [json.org](http://json.org/) has a diagram that shows the syntax. It’s extremely simple to understand, IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

**Json Syntax Includes following.**

```
 1. Data is represented in name/value pairs.
 2. Each name is followed by ':'(colon).
 3. The name/value pairs are separated by ,(comma).
 4. Json object starts and ends with '{' and '}'.
 5. Square brackets '[ ]' hold arrays and values are separated by
    ,(comma).
```

**Json Objects Example**

```
    {
    "id":"21",
    "language": "Json",
    "edition": "second",
    }
```

**Json Array Example**

```
  {
        "book": [
        {
        "id":"21",
        "language": "Json",
        "edition": "second"
        },
        {
        "id":"42",
        "language": "Json",
        "edition": "third"
        }]
        }
```

I have taken reference from http://www.tutsway.com/json-syntax.php

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote up there is already correct :)

```
[{ "username" : "admin", "password" : "123" }, { "username" : "bbvb", "password" : "sdfsdf" }, { "username" : "asd", "password" : "222" }]
```